# Email forwarding with Godaddy, SMTP2Go and Netlify

Tags: email, netlify

I cannot get email forwarding from my godaddy domain to my gmail. When I send an email to the address, I get the email (from my gmail only) and a message saying address not found.

Setup is:

1. Godaddy domain and emailforwarding
2. Netlify to mangage the DNS (it's where the site it managed too)
3. SMTP2GO to manage email sending an configuration

In GoDaddy, the MX settings are active with the green tickmark showing.

In Netlify, I have input the MX records from GoDaddy.

In SMTP2GO, the SPF and DKIM records are verified.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If netlify is managing DNS, then the MX records in Godaddy are ignored.  You can tell this by using whois:

```
$  whois fools.website | grep -i "name server"
Name Server: DNS1.P05.NSONE.NET
Name Server: DNS2.P05.NSONE.NET
Name Server: DNS3.P05.NSONE.NET
Name Server: DNS4.P05.NSONE.NET
```

Netlify's nameservers all match the same pattern of DNSx.P0X.NSONE.NET

If your whois lookup returns similar results, you'll want to instead configure everything you have in your DNS settings in Godaddy at Netlify's DNS config, usually https://app.netlify.com/account/dns/domain.name (where you replace domain.name with your actual domain name like mynetlifysite.com)

If your whois records look more like this:

```
 $  whois godaddysite.com | grep -i "name server"
 Name Server: PDNS03.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
 Name Server: PDNS04.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
```

Then you'd want to work with Godaddy's support on why the records aren't working as expected since they do host/manage your DNS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My whois records look like:

DNS1.P04.NSONE.NET (has 1,402,200 domains)
DNS2.P04.NSONE.NET (has 1,402,200 domains)
DNS3.P04.NSONE.NET (has 1,402,200 domains)
DNS4.P04.NSONE.NET (has 1,402,200 domains)

This is when I have Netlfiy managing the DNS.

So, you are saying that Netlify can't manage the MX records?

I don't understand what you mean by: 'If your whois lookup returns similar results, you'll want to instead configure everything you have in your DNS settings in Godaddy at Netlify's DNS config,'

Comment: Netlify can manage any record type.  I'm saying you need to add them individually in our UI.  Sounds like you should write in to the help desk (support@netlify.com) where we can talk about your actual domain name and give you better advice in configuration.  Please write in from an address that is working (e.g. gmail) rather than the one you are having trouble with email from :)

Comment: I have already inserted the DNS settings in the netlify DNS. Moreover, I emailed Netlfiy already. They couldn't offer any advice. I've removed SMTP2Go from my setup and it works. Now I need to figure out why SMTP2Go doesn't work. Thanks for your response. Will post here if I find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Point Godaddy's DNS to Netlify. Then from Netlify, add MX record of SMTP2GO. Lastly, create alias from STMP2GO that points to your Gmail email address. In my case, I'm using Namecheap instead of Godaddy and ImprovMX instead of SMTP2GO. I posted this here

https://marvintan.com/posts/free-custom-email-address/